# Displaying a photo in PictureBox from DB

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, picturebox

```
public EmployeeProfile(int EmpID)
{
      if (byteArrayToImage(Emp.Photo.ToArray()) != null)
            {
                pictureBoxEmp.Image = byteArrayToImage(Emp.Photo.ToArray());
                pictureBoxEmp.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            }
}
public Image byteArrayToImage(Byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
       Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
       return returnImage;
}
```

I have this code when an employee doesn't have a picture a message will appear:[image]

Comment: Please mention what you want to do exactly and show your entire code, to give you the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Emp.Photo` is `null` and calling `ToArray()` is giving you the null reference exception. Try this:

```
if (Emp.Photo != null)
{
    pictureBoxEmp.Image = byteArrayToImage(Emp.Photo.ToArray());
    pictureBoxEmp.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your `Emp` originally doesn't have a Photo, which means the Emp.Photo is null, that's why you're having the [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whose message is "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*", you need first to check if your Emp object has a Photo or not :

```
public EmployeeProfile(int EmpID)
        {
              if (Emp.Photo != null)
                    {
                        pictureBoxEmp.Image = byteArrayToImage(Emp.Photo.ToArray());
                        pictureBoxEmp.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **Emp** and **Photo** are not null:

```
public EmployeeProfile(int EmpID)
{
      if (Emp != null && Emp.Photo != null)
      {
           pictureBoxEmp.Image = byteArrayToImage(Emp.Photo.ToArray());
           pictureBoxEmp.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
      }
}
```